# Left Join using NHibernate Mapping

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

In my scenario I have a mapping of table in *.hbm.xml file as,

```
<class name="Student" table="Temp_Student" >
    <id name="StudentID" column="StudentID" type="AnsiString" />    
    <property name="Name" type="AnsiString" column="Name" />    
    <many-to-one name="ClassOperator" column="Class_OPERATOR" class="MvcProj.StudentClassRef" lazy="false"/>
</class>
```

Current implementation is making Inner join but i want to make Left Outer join. How can i do this with changes?

And through the code implementation.

```
private string GenerateSQL(ICriteria criteria, out QueryParameters queryParam)
{
    CriteriaImpl criteriaImpl = (CriteriaImpl)criteria;
    ISessionImplementor session = criteriaImpl.Session;
    ISessionFactoryImplementor factory = session.Factory;
    CriteriaQueryTranslator translator = 
        new CriteriaQueryTranslator(factory, 
            criteriaImpl, 
            criteriaImpl.EntityOrClassName, 
            CriteriaQueryTranslator.RootSqlAlias);
    String[] implementors = factory.GetImplementors(criteriaImpl.EntityOrClassName);
    CriteriaJoinWalker walker = 
        new CriteriaJoinWalker(
            (NHibernate.Persister.Entity.IOuterJoinLoadable)factory.GetEntityPersister(implementors[0]), 
            translator, 
            factory, 
            criteriaImpl,
            criteriaImpl.EntityOrClassName, 
            session.EnabledFilters);
    queryParameters = translator.GetQueryParameters();
    return walker.SqlString.ToString();
}
```

With above code I am able to generate Query with Inner join only and not Outer Join.
How can i make Outer join so that i can get my expected result.
I am using NHibernate version 3.1 here.

Answer (score -1):

You can try adding **inverse ="false"** to  edit *.hbm.xml file like this;

Comment: The answer is not related to the question, I am asking to do Left join.